# [Android]: Some questions about GoogleFusedLocation API

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm currently working on an Android app that use location to operate. Imagine that when you run app, it will display all near-by hotel.

After reading the Internet, I applied Google Fused Location to my app but some problem occurred and I have no idea how to solve it.

Here are my approach:

1. When SplashActivity start, I run the LocationService to create location request and request location update. I use HIGH_ACCURACY option and use both GPS and Network Provider.
2. In onLocationChanged() I call Geocode Intent Service to parse lat lng to address.
3. When Geocode Intent Service complete, I receive the result thanks to ResultReceiver (I did the exact same way like Google tutorial) and send a Broadcast to SplashActivity.
4. When SplashActivity receive broadcast, I start my MainActivity.

   - Please let me know if my approach is a correct way to use FusedLocationService, this is the 1st time I make location-based app.
   - Sometime, onLocationChanged() took so long to response (about 3 minutes, sometime forever). I notice that this problem occurred only on Android OS 5, 6, 7 (I do request permissions) but again sometime it really fast (1-2 secs). This problem is killing me, I have no idea how to solve this.
   - I'm thinking about apply last known location to solve the above problem, but I wonder if there is a way to set a time-out for requestLocationUpdate(). And my app need user current location to display data, so I don't think last known location is a good idea. Anyway, it's good to hear your opinion about this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is not a good idea , splash screen is for branding your application and to do small amount of work like check new version or check if there's connectivity available , I'd suggest to you to move your code to "MainActivity" and show a progress indication, and if you don't feel comfortable using the `Google Fused Location`  try to use https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib it will simplify the implementation of Location service , good luck :)

Comment: @MohamedRa Thanks for your suggest, I will consider moving the location code. But how about the long time receive location, do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, considering a location is fresh or old could depend on your scenario. I meant, a ten minutes old location maybe useful for weather app, but doesn't sound good for tracking intent.

**IMHO, the whole process seem a bit bad, you can give chance to receive location for user even after splash screen**

Anyways, i have a scenario for you

- Define a timeout value, for instance 10 seconds
- Make location request with immediately values (set interval and fastest interval 0)
- If you receive location, remove location updates, stop timeout and use location (for geocoder)
- We couldn't receive location and timeout finished, refer to last known location
- If the last known location is nice for us(mentioned in first paragraph) use location (for geocoder)

Comment: Thanks for your scenario, this is also what I'm thinking. Do you have any idea why sometime receive location took so long to response. When I'm testing, nothing happen but when user use my app, they keep reporting this issue

Comment: Because you tested the app on your device lots of time, and your device already received first-fix(TTFF), and probably your are near to roof or windows. For me, my device cant receive location update in office between walls.